# Connect Doctrine to a MS SQL Database

Tags: php, symfony, azure, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Just before i get started, I have been trying to figure this out and have clicked nearly every google link there is and I have read nearly all the other questions on this. But I'm stuck because the bundles that are being suggested for this are out of date.

I am creating a website. Tt is a symfony2 application that is being hosted on Microsoft azure. What I want to do is be able to use doctrine of course to fetch and create users to and from the database.

Now from what I've been reading, to connect to this type of database, I have to use the driver called "PDO_dblib".

I have installed this bundle as it seems to be the only one thats still active, don't quote me on that.

https://github.com/realestateconz/MssqlBundle

Now, I installed this in my vendor folder, is this the correct place to store it? Like so:

```
Project/
    app/
    src/
    vendor/
       realestate/
```

Of course i added the bundle to the AppKernel like so:

```
 new Realestate\MssqlBundle\RealestateMssqlBundle();
```

and last but not least here is what i have in my config file:

```
 doctrine:
     dbal:
       default_connection:     default
       connections:
           default:
               driver_class:   Realestate\MssqlBundle\Driver\PDODblib\Driver
               host:           %database_host%
               dbname:         %database_prefix%%database_name%
               user:           %database_user%
               password:       %database_password%
```

so what im thinking im doing here is telling doctrine to use this driver? dont see what else it could be.

I have also declared my parameters.yml for the connection settings.

PS: I am doing my Dev on Linux Mint!

before i tried the steps of this bundle i also ran throught this websites steps: https://dunglas.fr/2014/01/connection-to-a-ms-sql-server-from-symfony-doctrine-on-mac-or-linux/

But again it was throwing errors, I'll post the errors I get down below!
So for the record I have installed freetds and php5-sybase.

The errors that I am getting are such:

```
 [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]                                                               
 Warning: class_implements(): Class Realestate\MssqlBundle\Driver\PDODlib\Driver does not exist and could not be loaded
```

and also this when i try to do a:
    php app/console doctrine:database:create

(I do have my entity set up)

but i get the following error from the command of create:

```
 [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException]                                                 
 You have requested a non-existent parameter "database_prefix". Did you   mean one of these: "database_port", "database_user"?
```

I have been trying to get this working for the past few days and any help would be fantastic! Any more information needed feel free to ask of course!

Comment: How did you install the bundle? Using composer?

Comment: I couldnt find the require line, so i git cloned it into my vendor folder, would that cause the issues?

Comment: If you did not use composer then probably your autoload file did not get updated and this means you will not be able to load the files from that bundle. You could try to update this file manually but instead do yourself a favor and get composer to work so that you can install it using composer, this will make everything much easier

Comment: I just realised, i did use composer for this bundle, i git cloned another bundle that i tried, this one should be set up correctly

Answer (score 0):

According your error code:

> [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException]
>    You have requested a non-existent parameter "database_prefix". Did you   mean one of these: "database_port", "database_user"?

It seems that you miss configuring the parameter “database_prefix”.

If the tables in your database have the unitized prefix e.g. “core_user”,”core_tasks”… You can configure this parameter in the file `parameters.yml` if not, you can just remove the parameter `% database_prefix %` in the `dbname` line in file `config.yml`.

Here are my code snippets for your reference:

**Config.yml**:

`doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection:   default
        connections:
            default:
                driver_class:   Realestate\MssqlBundle\Driver\PDODblib\Driver
                host:           %database_host%
                port:           %database_port%
                dbname:         %database_name%
                user:           %database_user%
                password:       %database_password%`

**parameters.yml:**

`parameters:
    database_host: {your_sql_server_name}.database.windows.net
    database_port: 1433
    database_name: {database_name}
    database_user: {username}
    database_password: {password}`

And the test query in **controller**:

        `$conn = $this->get('database_connection');
        $data = $conn->fetchAll('SELECT * FROM Testtable');
        var_dump($data);`